# No USB digital sound on 17.10, but Win-10 sound is OK

Tags: usb, sound, 17.10, speakers, ubuntu-drivers

I just upgraded to U17.10 on a desktop that dual boots Windows, and has a pair of smal USB-powered speakers.
My Win-10 Insider Preview build 17025 has great sound, as do all past Windows and Ubuntu versions.
But Ubuntu 17.10 is SILENT.
When I press the vol-ctl buttons on the speaker, the Ubuntu screen shows a small sound window: - increasing/ decreasing, etc, and when off button is pressed, it will show a "DIGITAL OUTPUT S/PDIF" as switching on or off.
Alas, the speakers remain totally silent in U17.10, no matter what the "sound" scroller is set to.
Obviously, the USB speakers are detected by Ubuntu, as with Win-10, but-
Why is there no sound in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: Same problem here. Upgraded to 17.10 yesterday. No sound today.

Answer (score 0):

OK- This is **for AMD CPU users**- (I'm using an AMD Phenom-II)
finally fixed this by installing **MISSING PROPRIETARY DRIVERS!**
Go to "software and updates" and click the "Additional drivers: tab.
Wait a few secs to see if it finds any additional drivers.
In my case it found some missing microcode firmware for AMD CPUs.

Use this device, and **then update** via the "software updater" icon, or do an apt-get update.
 You may have to restart Ubuntu again.
Click on "Sound" in settings, check the sound there to make sure it IS TURNED ON (the changes above turned my sound OFF!) and then choose the appropriate setting .. digital or analog..